# Run time is longer when trying to resize array by twice

Tags: java, arrays, xor

I'm trying to operate XOR with two object sets that I've made.
For some reason it takes longer in big arrays (over 10,000 objects) for this method to run when I'm resizing by twice each time and then resizing by +10.
This is my resize function:

```
  private void resize(){
        System.out.println("resized");
        Fraction temp[] = new Fraction [this.arr.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        arr = temp;
    }
```

This is the XOR function:

```
public void xor(FractionSet other){
    FractionSet xor = new FractionSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(other.contains(arr[i]) == -1) xor.add(arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < other.size; i++) {
        if(this.contains(other.arr[i]) == -1) xor.add(other.arr[i]);
    }
    this.arr = xor.arr;
    this.size = xor.size;
}
```

This is the add function:

```
public void add(Fraction elem){
    if(this.contains(elem) != -1) return;
    else{
        if(size == arr.length) this.resize();
        arr[size] = elem;
        size++;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `resize()` method has to copy more elements when the array is bigger. Therefore your execution time is higher. For performance reasons, you should use [`System.arraycopy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) instead of a `for` loop to copy the data, but I suspect this will only help marginally. Also, [you should double the array size rather than growing by a constant factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost).

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean. It doesn't help that you've only posted snippets. Please post a [mvce].

Comment: if im resizing the array by * 2 , the run time is much longer then resizing by constant (+10) , cant understand why its happen.

Comment: not related to the question but why make `contains` return integer, just return boolean !